# d3 append invisible if data is not same as previous

Tags: d3.js, comparison

d3 newb is trying something else:
I want to add a date label to my bar chart only if the date is not the same as in the previous bar.

```
bar.append("text")
    .attr("visibility", function(d,i){
        if(d.Datum == data[i-1].Datum) return "hidden"})
    .attr("x", padding)
    .attr("y", barHeight-2)
    .attr("fill", "Gainsboro")
    .text(function(d){ return d.Datum})
```

So I thought I add a visibility to my text label. however I cannot access the previous date from the data-object... probably this is an easy one for someone not newbie as me...

data example (before CSV import)

```
Datum,Name,Kategorie,Betrag
01/10/15,,Lohn,1586.7
02/10/15,,lunch,-4.55
```

Comment: What's the `data` object that's bound to the bar?  `d.Datum` contains the text label?  You'd be better off using a `.filter` here and not appending the `text` at all.  Add an example of `data` to your question.

Comment: @Mark I added a data sample. I hope that's what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming that after `d3` parses the text file you are left with data like:

```
var data = [
    {
      Datum: "01/10/15",
      Name: "",
      Kategorie: "Lohn",
      Betrag: 1586.7
    },{
      ...
    }
  ];
```

I'd pre-process the data to contain a `bool` about whether or not it is the first instance of that date:

```
  data.forEach(function(d,i){
    d.isFirstInstanceOfDate = (i === 0 || d.Dataum !== data[i-1].Datum);
  });
```

Then assuming that `bar` is a selection of `g`s elements (which already contain a `rect`), I'd filter them and only append the `text` on the first instance:

```
  bar
    .filter(function(d){
      return d.isFirstInstanceOfDate
    })
    .append('text')
    ...
```

Comment: thanks! this is a great explanation and a good way to think about d3-data structures like this. Makes a lot of sense to me at least!

Answer (score 0):

The index starts from 0. By subtracting 1 from it the first time you get an error. You need to check whether i > 0 so that you don't do out of bounds.

For example:

```
  .style('visibility', function (d, i) {
    if (i > 0) {
      if (d.datetime === data[i - 1].datetime) {
        return 'hidden';
      }
    }
    return 'visible';
  });
```

Here are two sample fiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/00drii/y079vw7e/

http://jsfiddle.net/00drii/dmhs0gza/